# How to match ID field with its sequence?

Tags: database, postgresql, metadata

I've a handful of tables with PK that are taken from dedicated sequences. Unfortunately, I suppose that one of those sequences is used twice (to generate an ID) for two different tables. Is it possible to write a query that will return all the fields (the field name is always `ID`) and sequences that are used the generate a default value for those fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query lists table names and sequences associated with the `id` column of the tables:

```
select 
    nspname as schema, 
    relname as table,
    trim(substring(pg_get_expr(adbin, adrelid), e'\'.*\''), '''') as sequence
from pg_attribute a
join pg_attrdef d on adrelid = attrelid and adnum = attnum 
join pg_class c on c.oid = attrelid
join pg_namespace n on n.oid = relnamespace
where attname = 'id' and atthasdef
and left(pg_get_expr(adbin, adrelid), 7) = 'nextval';

 schema |    table     |      sequence       
--------+--------------+---------------------
 public | test_table   | test_table_id_seq
 public | log          | log_id_seq
 public | master       | master_id_seq
 public | details      | details_id_seq
 ...
```

You can skip the condition `attname = 'id'`. The query finds columns which have a function `nextval()` as a default expression, e.g.:

```
select 
    nspname as schema, 
    relname as table,
    attname as column,
    trim(substring(pg_get_expr(adbin, adrelid), e'\'.*\''), '''') as sequence
from pg_attribute a
join pg_attrdef d on adrelid = attrelid and adnum = attnum 
join pg_class c on c.oid = attrelid
join pg_namespace n on n.oid = relnamespace
where atthasdef
and left(pg_get_expr(adbin, adrelid), 7) = 'nextval';

 schema |    table     |  column   |       sequence        
--------+--------------+-----------+-----------------------
 public | test_table   | id        | test_table_id_seq
 public | log          | id        | log_id_seq
 public | wallets      | wallet_id | wallets_wallet_id_seq
 public | master       | id        | master_id_seq
 public | details      | id        | details_id_seq
 ...
```